# Is the weak limit of tight (Radon) measures tight as well?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space. Remember that a family $\mathcal F$ of finite signed measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ is called *(uniformly) tight* if for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact $K\subseteq E$ with $\sup_{\mu\in\mathcal F}|\mu|(K^c)<\varepsilon$. A finite signed measure $\mu$ is called *tight* if $\{\mu\}$ is tight.

Now assume $\mu_n$ is a tight finite signed measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $\mu$ is a finite signed measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ such that $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\to\mu$ weakly, i.e. $$\int f\:{\rm d}\mu_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int f\:{\rm d}\mu$$ for all bounded continuous $f:E\to\mathbb R$.

> Are we able to conclude that $\mu$ is tight as well?

Maybe we need to assume that $(E,d)$ is complete, since then Prohorov's theorem implies that even $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is (uniformly) tight (and bounded in total variation).

Please feel free to assume completeness.

Comment: If $E$ is complete, then any finite signed measure on $\mathcal{B}(E)$ is tight.

Comment: @MaoWao Unless I'm missing something, we need to assume that $E$ is complete **and** separable to ensure that every finite signed measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ is tight (hence Radon).

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Sorry, what is the meaning of "$\{\mu\}$"? You say that a finite signed measure $\mu$ is called tight whenever $\{\mu\}$ is tight.

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman $\{\mu\}$ is the set consisting of the single element $\mu$.

Comment: If the space is Polish, both the positive and negative measures of $\mu$ (Hahn decomposition) are tight (Ulam). Furthermore, $\{\mu_n\}$ is uniformly bounded in finite variation (Prohorov). A good place to see this things is Bogachev's Measure Theory volume 2.